# Matlab: Checking exsistence of solutions for non-square linear system.

Tags: matlab, math-software

I am interested in seeing how to check if there is a consistent solution for a linear system which does not have a square matrix.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, linsolve does not work(at least how I am using).

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to compute the RREF of the augmented matrix and see if you obtain a row of all $0$'s but with last entry being $1$, if that is the case then it is not consistent because that would mean $0=1$.

Otherwise it is consistent.

Comment: RREF: **R**educed **R**ow **E**chelon **F**orm.

Comment: Hello, thank you - how would I go about solving the system once I knew it was consistent? Basically I need to check consistency than solve for a solution if it is consistent

Comment: If you just want a solution, try linsolve?

Comment: Good point, I think linsolve will produce a consistent solution if one exists.